# angularjs local development environment setup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I use this boilerplate https://github.com/node90/angular-starter as a starter. But the repo use gulp to concatenate `app` folder's js into `public/js`. Means every time I make a small change on any files on `app` folder, I have to run `gulp`? that doesn't make sense, need help how to set that up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would include [watch](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb) in your gulp configuration so it would automatically rerun the concatenation task when you made a change.

Comment: the command takes 30 sec to finish everything, it's a pain to wait to see changes

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the gulp configuration file you will see that there is a 'watch' task defined.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('public/css/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/partials/**/*.html', ['templates']);
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.js', ['angular']);
});
```

If you run "gulp watch" from the command line, the watch task will be executed. The default gulp task is to build the app and run watch.

Comment: how do I avoid this? I only do this when I'm ready for production, it's a pain to wait 30 sec to do unnecessary gulp task during coding.

Comment: I modified app/index.html to this http://pastebin.com/WZ6UAh6u but it doesn't load app.js, any idea?

Comment: The gulp 'angular' task generates an _application.js_ file and places it in the **public/js** folder. Where is the _app.js_ file coming from?

Comment: inside app folder